# Vaadin: Dynamically modifying Tabs in a TabSheet

Tags: java, vaadin

Let's say I have Four Tabs.

There are some other tabs, which have the above Tabs as their parent.

For Example,

Tab1 : Parent: none, Tab2: Parent: none, Tab3: Parent: Tab2.

Say if I get this information **during Run time**, and I parse it to find their parents.

If I have a tab that has no parents, I simply create a new Tab and add this tab to it.

Now once I find that I have a tab which has a parent Tab, I need to go to the parent tab, and append this tab to it.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple recursive traversal over a Stack which stored the components, and a description equality evaluator for them to find the match did the trick.